# in Angularjs JSON is returned but not displayed in table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

the code below, creates a table of data and works OK.

```
******************* works OK**************************

//angularjs to fetch JSON data for table

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("http://test2.aspx")
.then(function (response) {$scope.recds = response.data.records;

********************************************************
```

I want to click on a table line and dynamically create a second table with charge data. The code below returns a correct JSON file, which is displayed in the alarm, but does not display in the generated html.....the table is created but the angularjs JSON placeholders are just displayed: eg { x.Charges }.

Does anybody have any ideas why please?

```
//angularjs to fetch JSON data for charges
    $scope.go=function(x) {
        
        
            
                $http.get("http:///Charges.aspx?ac=" + x)
                .then(function (response) {$scope.chgs = response.data;
                
                alert(JSON.stringify($scope.chgs.records2));

*********************** Doesn't work************************************                    
                var lines='<table>';
                lines +='<tr>';
                lines +='<th>Account</th>';
                lines +='<th>Chargecode</th>';
                lines +='<th>Rate</th>';
                lines +='</tr>';
                lines +='<tr ng-repeat="x in chgs">';
                lines +='<td>{{ x.Customer }}</td>';
                lines +='<td>{{ x.ChargeCode }}</td>';
                lines +='<td>{{ x.Charge }}</td>';
                lines +='</tr>';
                lines +='</table>';
                document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML=lines;
                document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = 'visible';
                //})
                })  
                        
    }
************************************************************************************
})
})
```

Many Thanks

Rob

[image: sample charge JSON file]

Comment: Why are you using dynamic html?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-scope-apply-in-angularjs/

Comment: The Scion ... I tried with a static table but the result was the same.

Comment: Aaah!! really don't understand this. No errors, code looks OK to me but the table fails to populate.

Comment: Create js fiddle so we can play with it, do it with a static table (should be a better approach)

Comment: Hi as required... https://jsfiddle.net/Buzz15uk/hwnLb0t1/9/

Comment: Are you sure that http://test2.aspx really returns records?

Comment: Hi, yes. running the charge table singularly displays the data in the table but not together.

Comment: Added a sample of the charges JSON file.

Comment: Wondering if data not being pulled back before the table is displayed.